# Different behaviour of os.writev on Ubuntu and Mac

Tags: macos, python-3.x

I have experienced some difficulties with function `os.writev` in Python3.5 when used on mac. On Linux (Ubuntu) everything works as expected but when I pass empty list on mac:

```
os.writev(descriptor, [])
```

I get error - `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`. 
Is this incompatibility worth reporting somewhere or is it expected behaviour?

Note that [according to documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.writev) it should be available on unix, which should apply also for osx.